# Using pdfx with LuaLaTeX results in error

Tags: luatex, pdfx

When I try to compile the following MWE with lualatex (on Miktex), i get this error:

```
! LuaTeX error (ext5): cannot open file for embedding.
\reserved@a ...viceRGB} file{"\pdfx@rgb@profile "}
                                                  \edef \OBJ@RGB {\the \pdfl...
l.742  }
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
  \Title{Test PDF/A-1b}
  \Author{Me}
  %\setRGBcolorprofile{./sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc}
  %  {sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled}
  %  {sRGB IEC61966 v2.1 with black scaling}
  %  {http://www.color.org}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

The error message points to the color profiles that should be loaded, but also adding the profile explicitly to the xmpdata file (after copying the profile from the pdfx-folder to the current working folder) doesn’t change the result. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The pdfx code puts quotes around the file name and luatex seems not to like it. It works fine if I change line 723 to `\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3^^J/Alternate/DeviceRGB} file{\pdfx@rgb@profile}`. I don't know if this a bug or not. But I will ask on the luatex list.

Comment: Imho all the quotes in `file{" ... "}` are unnecessary. With pdflatex they seem to do no harm, but as luatex doesn't like them they should be removed. I wrote to one of the authors of pdfx.

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike! If you like, please post this information as an answer and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for pdfx](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) (at the moment under "2.5 Color Profiles") points out, that the color profile must be specified.

The problem @ulrike-fischer found has probably vanished. The MWE compiles fine for me with both LuaLaTeX – Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) – and PDFLaTeX. A sole warning from `hyperref` package about page height stains the log.

### maybe the documentation helps …

You intend to create a PDF/A compliant document, so have a look into guidelines that try to help for that, e.g. in [Instructions for creating PDF/A-compliant files for online publishing at the TU Berlin](https://www.ub.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/pdf/Verlag/UV_pdfaEN.pdf).

You will learn, that the privided `xmp` data is not sufficient. You need: title, author, keywords, publisher (or more). That also is told in the `pdfx` manual (in section "2.2 Data file for metadate")

According to the TU Berlin you may validate e.g. with [pdflib.com](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/xmp-metadata/free-xmp-validator/).

It links towards http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter where described how to do get the profiles.

tl;dr:

```
wget http://www.color.org/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc -O sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm
```

The file shall be next to your main jobfile (so next to the `xmpdata`-file) and also is provided by the `pdfx` [package itself on CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/).

If that all sounds like news, head on e.g. to [this guide about PDF/A](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/pdfa/#step1).