# Compile as PDF-A

Tags: compiling, texstudio, pdf-a

I am running my LaTeX from the TexStudio GUI.  How can I compile/export to PDF/A format?  Is there an easy way to do it without converting through some external method?

Comment: To convert your existing PDF to PDF/A you can use the [preflight tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/analyzing-documents-preflight-tool-acrobat.html) of Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfx now accesses the default RGB and CMYK profiles using the new  colorprofiles package; in particular using a file called colorprofiles.tex (as well as  colorprofiles.sty ).
A change in the distributed profiles was forced by a change in the licensing of a previous file, making it no longer free to be distributed with Linux distributions; hence not with TeXLive.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the package https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx. It has options to for various PDF/A-standards and I used it successfully on one of my projects. You should pay attention to the manual.

**Edit:**
Please read the fine manual (RTFM); there is not always free lunch in `TeX`. E.g. sections 1, 2.5: you could write a file `jobname.xmpdata` with the contents

```
\pdfxSetCMYKcolorProfileDir{/myDirectory/ColorSync/Profiles/}
\setCMYKcolorprofile{PSO_Uncoated_ISO12647_eci.icc}
                    {PSO_Uncoated_ISO12647_eci}
                    {PSO Uncoated ISO12647 (ECI)}
                    {http://www.eci.org/en/start}
```

where your color profiles are installed in the directory mentioned above. You can download color profiles from http://www.eci.org/en/downloads.

You could also pay attention to [Using pdfx with LuaLaTeX results in error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301616/using-pdfx-with-lualatex-results-in-error).

Please pay attention to the comments by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/85415/dd23 below.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting the "No color profile found to use for RGB screen colors." error from the pdfx.sty file

Comment: @AIM_BLB As I said, you need to pay attention to the manual. The package (or the standard, resp) requires to fix a color profile, compare section 2.5 of the manual.

Comment: How do you do that?  I don;t understand

Comment: There is also the `xmpincl` package that produces pdf/a files, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314171/avoiding-errors-with-includexmppdfa-1b-any-list-of-best-practices-and-workin/

Comment: @AIM_BLB If you don't understand the implications, it might not be such a good idea to try to generate PDF/A.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have to for thesis reasons, unfortunately :////

Comment: The pdfx manual in section 2.5 also says
"Since most LaTeX users are not graphics professionals and are not particularly picky about colors, the pdfx package includes default profiles that will be included when nothing else is specified. Therefore, the average user doesn’t have to do anything special about color."

Without specifying anything (this used to work until the most recent texlive update on Arch Linux), I'm now also getting the following error: "pdfx.sty:1301: No color profile found to use for RGB screen colors".
Even when I try to specify icc files, the error remains.

Comment: Apparently texlive has recently renamed some color profiles…
Adding the following to your \jobname.xmpdata fixes my problem:
\setRGBcolorprofile{sRGB.icc}
{sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled}
{sRGB IEC61966 v2.1 with black scaling}
{http://www.color.org}

The .icc file had a different name before…