# How to reuse color profile file in multiple documents?

Tags: external-files

I am trying to reuse files in multiple documents, but I am having problems with the color profile file.

The idea is to have the .icc file in the `icc` folder inside the main folder and access that file from the different documents that I am going to create.

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4} file{../icc/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
    /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S/GTS_PDFX
    /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /Info(ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
    >> ]
}
\pdfinfo{% not needed with newer PDF/X versions
    /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)%
    /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)%
}
```

Here `file{../icc/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc}` I thought it would look for the file in the `icc` folder of the parent directory, but that doesn't happen, it tells me that it can't find the document. If I put the file in the folder where the `.tex` file is, the error disappears and the document compiles without problems.

How can I include the color profile from the `icc` folder of the parent directory?

This is my folder tree:

```
├── parent\
│   ├── ciclo-A\ 
│   │   ├── vol-1\
│   │   │   └── 00-main.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter01.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter02.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter01.tex
│   │   ├── vol-2\
│   │   │   └── 00-main.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter01.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter02.tex
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── vol-3
│   ├── ciclo-B\ 
│   │   ├── vol-1\
│   │   │   └── 00-main.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter01.tex
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── vol-2\
│   │   │   └── 00-main.tex
│   │   │   └── p01-chapter01.tex
│   │   │   └── ...
│   ├── icc\ 
│   │   └── ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc
└── main-template.tex
```

### Important clarification:

This is the order in which I link the files:

Suppose I am going to work on the document that I will create in `vol-1`.

#### One

In the file `parent/ciclo-A/vol-1/00-main.tex` I load the following:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany,showtrims,titlepage]{memoir}
\newcommand\theAuthor{ACG }
\newcommand\titleA{HD (A) *Documento Provisional*}
\newcommand\titleB{Adv}
\newcommand\theKeywords{Homilías\sep Liturgia\sep Cristianismo\sep Iglesia Católica}
\newcommand\theSubject{Esta obra recoge las homilías dominicales de los últimos papas. Contiene además las lecturas bíblicas según el nuevo Leccionario de la Misa, Comentarios Patrísticos a los Evangelios y los Temas del Catecismo de la Iglesia Católica sugeridos por el Directorio Homilético}
\newcommand\theOrg{www.example.org}
\newcommand\isCopyrighted{TRUE}
\newcommand\thePublicationType{Book}
\newcommand\theVolume{1}
\newcommand\thePublisher{example.org}
\newcommand\theYear{2021}
\newcommand\volume{Volumen 2}
\newcommand\subTitle{Textos bíblicos del nuevo Leccionario de la Misa, \\Comentarios Patrísticos a los Evangelios \\y Temas del Directorio Homilético}

\RequirePackage{filecontents} %if filecontents should overwrite old files

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{\titleA \titleB}
    \Author{\theAuthor}
    \Volume{\theVolume}
    \Subject{\theSubject}
    \Keywords{\theKeywords} 
    \Org{\theOrg}
    \Copyrighted{\isCopyrighted}
    \PublicationType{\thePublicationType}
\end{filecontents}

\input{../../main-template} 

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \label{files}
    \input{p01-chapter01}
    % ...
    
\end{document}
```

#### Two

As you can see, within `00-main.tex` I load the file `main-template.tex` in this line: `\input{../../main-template}` and this is the file that loads the `icc` file:

**`main-template.tex`**:

```
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4} file{../icc/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
    /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S/GTS_PDFX
    /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /Info(ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
    >> ]
}
\pdfinfo{% not needed with newer PDF/X versions
    /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)%
    /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)%
}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448549/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have tried `\pdfxSetCMYKcolorProfileDir` and `\setCMYKcolorprofile` without success.

Comment: I tested your set-up and it compiles nicely when using the correct relative path for the .icc file. On the basis of the directory structure you state above, you need to refer to the .icc file with `parent/icc/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc`, so you need to use the path from `main-template.tex` and not from `parent/ciclo-A/vol-1/00-main.tex`, even if this is the file you want to compile.

Comment: General comment: It is not always necessary to attach the *.icc file to PDF/X files, whether or not CMYK. You do need to specify an Output Intent. Always ask your print service whether or not to attach the profile. If the PDF/X does not have color, then almost certainly do NOT attach the *.icc profile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this can help you, since it does not use the `pdfx` package, but I once had a similar arrangement and used the `hyperref` package and XeLaTeX (it seems not to work with PDFLaTeX though) with the following set up. The .icc file is located in the parent directory of the .tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\def\iccprofilepath{../PSOcoated_v3.icc}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \special{pdf:minorversion 3}
  \special{pdf:docinfo <<
   /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)
   /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)
  >>}%
  \special{pdf:fstream @cmykdata (\iccprofilepath) <<
   /N 4^^J/Alternate/DeviceCMYK
  >>}%
  \special{pdf:put @catalog <<
   /PageMode /UseNone
   /OutputIntents [<<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S /GTS_PDFX
    /DestOutputProfile @cmykdata
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (PSOcoated_v3)
    /Info(PSO coated v3)
    /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
   >>]
  >>}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, is this possible to implement this in `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF` (PS2PDF using Acrobat distiller) ?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I don't think that this is possible, because you don't directly create a PDF using LaTeX this way. You would need to tell `ps2pdf` to include these, I would say.